# Evaluating a sum involving multinomial coefficient

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

$$S(p,x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}\sum_{a+b\le n,0\le b<a}\binom{n}{a,b,n-a-b}x^ay^b(1-x-y)^{n-a-b}$$

I am unable to simplify the sum. Mathematica doesn't help either. Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: I was trying to solve https://projecteuler.net/problem=661
There must be some way to evaluate the sum.

Comment: I can't particularly envision a way to make this (meaningfully) simpler. Where exactly did this sum come up, and why does it necessarily need to be simplified? Depending on the application you might not necessarily need a simplification even if it would be easier to work with.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check the link attached.